# Why am I getting all these errors in my C++ code?

Tags: c++

So I have this simple C++ code here, and nothing is underlined red, but when I go compile it, the console shows 4 errors at line 10, 4 at line 20, and 3 at line 21.

```
//Comment


#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

string comb(vector<int> table) { //Line 10
    string ret = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < table.size(); i++) {
        ret = ret + to_string(table[i]);
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> tab = { 3,4,5,6,7,99 };
    cout << comb(tab);
}
```

Comment: If only there was a way to copy and paste the errors...

Comment: Please post the error messages as well.

Comment: Please copy and paste the error message here :)

Comment: [Works for me](http://rextester.com/CYTJ40502)

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out `#include "stdafx.h"`, your code is fine.

Example:

```
//Comment


#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

//#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

string comb(vector<int> table) { 
    string ret = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < table.size(); i++) {
        ret = ret + to_string(table[i]);
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> tab = { 3,4,5,6,7,99 };
    cout << comb(tab);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I understand now, I put #include "stdafx.h" under all the #include.